# django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: cannot perform saving of other object in model within transaction

Tags: django, django-orm

Can't seem to find much info about this. This is NOT happening in a django test. I'm using `DATABASES = { ATOMIC_REQUESTS: True }`. Within a method (in mixin I created) called by the view, I'm trying to perform something like this:

```
def process_valid(self, view):
    old_id = view.object.id
    view.object.id = None       #  need a new instance in db
    view.object.save()
    old_fac = Entfac.objects.get(id=old_id)
    new_fac = view.object
    old_dets = Detfac.objects.filter(fk_ent__id__exact = old_fac.id)

    new_formset = view.DetFormsetClass(view.request.POST, instance=view.object, save_as_new=True)
    if new_formset.is_valid():
        new_dets = new_formset.save()

    
    new_fac.fk_cancel = old_fac    # need a fk reference to initial fac in new one
    old_fac.fk_cancel = new_fac    # need a fk reference to new in old fac

    # any save() action after this crashes with TransactionManagementError
    new_fac.save()
```

I do not understand this error. I already created & saved a new object in db (when I set the object.id to None & saved that). Why would creating other objects create an issue for further saves?

I have tried not instantiating the new_dets objects with the Formset, but instead explicitely defining them:

```
new_det = Detfac(...)
new_det.save()
```

But then again, any further save after that raises the error.

Further details:

Essentially, I have an `Entfac` model, and a `Detfac` model that has a foreignkey to `Entfac`. I need to instantiate a new `Enfac` (distinct in db), as well as corresponding new `Detfac` for the new `Entfac`. Then I need to change some values in some of the fields for both new & old objects, and save all that to db.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. The code above is fine.

But turns out, signals can be bad. I had forgotten that upon saving `Detfac,` there is a signal that goes to another class and that depending on the circumstances, adds a record to another table (sort of an history table).

Since that signal is just a single operation. Something like that:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Detfac)
def quantity_adjust_detfac(sender, **kwargs):
        try:
            detfac_qty = kwargs["instance"].qte
            product = kwargs["instance"].fk_produit
            if kwargs["created"]:
                initial = {# bunch of values}
                adjustment = HistoQuantity(**initial)
                adjustment.save()
            else:
        except TypeError as ex:
            logger.error(f"....")
        except AttributeError as ex:
            logger.error(f"....")
```

In itself, the fact that THIS wasn't marked as atomic isn't problematic. BUT if one of those exception throws, THEN I get the transactionmanagementerror. I am still not 100% sure why, tough the django docs do mention that when wrapping a whole view in atomic (or any chunk of code for that matter), then try/except within that block can yield unexpected result, because DJango does rely on exception to decide whether or not to commit the transaction as a whole. And the data I was testing with actually threw the exception (type error when creating the HistoQuantity object).

Wrapping the try/exception with a transaction.atomic manager worked however. Guessing that this... removed/handled the throw, thus the outer atomic could work.